# opengl problem with QT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using QT with opengl to make a chart in order to use it in different simulated physical experiments, but I'm facing the following problem.
I can't see my chart line unless I minimized my form window and then maximized it, and I should do that all the time as long as my line chart is being drawn in order to get the full result!!
What can I do, this is urgent and I need this chart working properly without minimizing and maximizing.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you aren't doing a repaint until minimize/maximize. I suggest using a timer to get the job done. Posting your code will help!!

Comment: you mean calling "updateGL()"?, sorry I can't post the code, it's like a huge project.

Comment: Create a test-case and post that :)

Comment: Are you using QGLWidget, inheriting from something, or using an embedded context?  Basically, what type of widget is doing the rendering and display?

Comment: Yep, I'm inheriting from QGLWidget.

Answer (score 2):

That's right batbrat, the missing call is **updateGL**, I used the following timer and it all worked, thanks.

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer( this );
connect( timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()));
timer->start(6);
```

Comment: Thanks for making me notice that, I'm still new here :)